--user-dir in Fairseq in failing
I’m trying to fine-tune the IndicTrans2 model using fairseq-train, but I keep encountering the following error:
fairseq-train: error: argument --user-dir: invalid Optional value: 'C:/Users/sasid/Downloads/en-indic-exp/model_configs'
I’ve provided the --user-dir argument as the path to the model_configs directory (e.g., --user-dir C:/Users/sasid/Downloads/IndicTrans2/model_configs), but the training script fails with the above error.
I figured out that the problem is it's not taking path in windows convention with backslashes instead it is taking forward slashes so it is failing with that error.
So how can I make it take the path in windows convention?

Try with double backslash, I will work. If you encounter some other error then share that error with proper log.
Code:
--user-dir C:\\Users\\sasid\\Downloads\\IndicTrans2\\model_configs

